# Initialize database values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project, i have a situation like when user runs the application.
The system should insert some values in a table which is used allover the application.
(These value should be inserted only once when the project is executed at first time)

I am trying to find out if there is any initialization function like Constructors in Rails.
I tried to use the **config/application.rb**, but i am not sure its the right way to do this.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: use the migration and insert value into tables .

Comment: is it possible for me to insert values into table with migration script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you looking for inserting some default dictionary data like month names etc you should look into `seed.rb` file or even better consider using `seed_fu` gem (https://github.com/mbleigh/seed-fu)

Answer (score 1):

**Yes** you can insert/edit/delete records into table with migration :

1) Create the migration .

2) Run db query inside the execute. like :

execute "insert into users (name, role) values ('vik', 'admin')"

3) After all the insertion operation run the migration.

Answer (score 0):

How if you update have boolean field or any kind of integer field to maintain status in your application. And for the very first time, user runs the application, your code will insert necessary values for that user in db and update boolean/status field and will be cached(for better performance only rather than fetching value from db every time). However after every time cache is cleared, it will send the query to db; but fetching boolean value(checking user status) is more faster than checking all inserted values for that user.